# Tips on effectively representing this recurrence relation in a generalized form.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, recurrence-relations

The recurrence relation is
$$
y_n = d_1 y_{n-1}+\frac{d}{dx}[y_{n-1}]
$$
a good thing to note as well is
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[d_n] = d_{n+1}
$$

This is terrible to expand out after a good while, The main goal is to represent this as a summation or as a function of some sort. I would rather officially solve myself So tips would be ideal, but answers are great too.

Comment: Might you mean ${d\over dx}(y_n)=y_{n+1}$ instead?

Comment: @JohnD no, you can solve for $\frac{d}{dx}(y_n)$ by manipulating the recurrence relation,

$\frac{d}{dx}(y_n) = y_{n+1}-d_1 y_n$